# Updating form responses from one sheet to another

Tags: excel, vba

I created a data entry form in Excel.

I would like that input to be stored in another sheet (Table format).

Code I found online and modified:

```vb
Function ValidateForm() As Boolean
    SellerSKU.BackColor = vbWhite
    Description.BackColor = vbWhite

    ValidateForm = True

    If Trim(SellerSKU.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "SKU can't be left blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "SKU"
        SellerSKU.BackColor = vbRed
        SellerSKU.Activate
        ValidateForm = False

    ElseIf Trim(Description.Value) = "" Then
        MsgBox "Description can't be left blank.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Description"
        Description.BackColor = vbRed
        Description.Activate
        ValidateForm = False
    End If

End Function


Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SellerSKU.Value = ""
    SellerSKU.BackColor = vbWhite

    Description.Value = ""
    Description.BackColor = vbWhite

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Dim iRow As Long

    iRow = Sheets("Reference Sheet (Order Hist)").Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row + 1

    If ValidateForm = True Then

        With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reference Sheet (Order Hist)")
            .Range("A" & iRow).Value = SellerSKU.Value
            .Range("C" & iRow).Value = Description.Value
        End With
        Call Reset
    Else
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

When I hit "Enter" on the data entry form, the table on the other sheet does not get updated.

Also is it possible to clear the form every time an entry has been successfully made?

Comment: What is `If ValidateForm = True Then` doing?

Comment: Looks a lot like https://thedatalabs.org/data-entry-form/   Did you write a `ValidateForm` function as shown there ?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes i got the code from there! i've updated my post to show the full code for clarity. Did i make a mistake?

Comment: @BigBen Sorry for the confusion, i only posted part of the code, I've updated the full code that i input into the post

Comment: We can't tell what `ValidateForm` is doing? As Tim said, did you write a `ValidateForm` function?

Comment: @BigBen I followed the code given by https://thedatalabs.org/data-entry-form/ . the other ValidateForm function I've written is in the first and fourth line - is that what youre referring to?

Comment: @BigBen I've tested the code out on a separate new excel sheet and it updates accordingly but when i change the sheet name to my existing sheet "Reference Sheet (Order Hist)", the table does not update

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me.  Re-organized and removed some of the repetition...

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim iRow As Long, valErrors As String
    
    valErrors = ValidationErrors() 'checks the form
    
    If Len(valErrors) = 0 Then
        'no errors - add the data
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reference Sheet (Order Hist)")
            iRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1
            .Range("A" & iRow).Value = SellerSKU.Value
            .Range("C" & iRow).Value = Description.Value
        End With
        ResetForm  'Call keyword is deprecated...
    Else
        MsgBox "One or more errors in form entries:" & vbLf & vbLf & valErrors, _
                vbOKOnly + vbExclamation, "Check form data"
    End If
   
End Sub

'check the form and return a listing of any errors
Function ValidationErrors() As String
    Dim msg As String
    
    CheckNonBlank SellerSKU, "SKU can't be left blank.", msg
    CheckNonBlank Description, "Description can't be left blank.", msg
    ValidationErrors = msg
End Function

'utility sub - check if a control has text, flag as error if missing,
'   and add some text to the overall validation message
Sub CheckNonBlank(cntrl As Object, msgErr As String, ByRef msg As String)
    Dim isErr As Boolean
    isErr = Len(Trim(cntrl.Value)) = 0 'true if no content
    ErrorFlag cntrl, isErr
    If isErr And Len(msgErr) > 0 Then
        msg = msg & IIf(Len(msg) > 0, vbLf, "") & msgErr 'append this error
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    ResetForm
End Sub

'clear textboxes and any error flags
Sub ResetForm()
    SellerSKU.Value = ""
    ErrorFlag SellerSKU, False
    Description.Value = ""
    ErrorFlag Description, False
End Sub

'flag a control as having a problem (pass False to second parameter to clear flag)
Sub ErrorFlag(cntrl As Object, Optional HasError As Boolean = True)
    cntrl.BackColor = IIf(HasError, vbRed, vbWhite)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The code is running well, but for some reason it only adds data from Row 26189 onwards but my table ends at 17461. How do I get the data to add on the code from 17461?

Comment: There must be some "invisible" content around there...

Comment: Try using Ctrl+Up from the bottom of ColA and see where it stops

Comment: Thank you. 1 more question, if i have a normal cell with the =now() function, is it possible to transfer the date as a value to the other data sheet as well?

Comment: You can use Now() directly in VBA.  It doesn't need to be in a cell.  Eg `.Range("D" & iRow).Value = Now`

Comment: Is there any way to have an autocomplete feature on the textbox such that when I enter the Product Name it will be autocompleted halfway? Thank you again